# ES modules old syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript, module

I'm learning `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `esModuleInterop` in TypeScript config, and I just realized the existence of ESM old syntax like the following.

```
import foo = require("foo");
export bar = xxx;
```

When/Who did start to support these syntax? or Can I get some references describing them?

Comment: That’s not “ESM old syntax”. That’s syntax for a different module system altogether. Honestly do a search on “module require”, and you’ll find the history pretty quick...

Comment: `import=` and `export=` are TS-specific hacks to support commonjs `require`:     https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require